# Custom taxonomy not showing terms in post area

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have created a custom taxonomy called `Country` to collect posts (even from different categories) under `country` terms. I used the following code, and I created terms with no problem:

```
function country_init() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'country',
        'post',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Country' ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'country' ),
            'capabilities' => array(
                'manage_terms' => 'manage_options',
                'edit_terms'   => 'manage_options',             
                'assign_terms' => 'edit_guides',
            )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'country_init' );
```

I am not able to choose those terms while creating a new **post**. The widget area shows the box named `country`, but toggling nothing as in the following picture. And there are no `country` boxes while creating menus or widgets.

[image: empty widget]

Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: try removing the `capabilities` array and see if that changes anything..

Comment: I had to change `'hierarchical'` to `true` in my taxonomy definition to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like its creating some conflict. Can you try with this code ?

```
add_action( 'init', 'country_init' );

function country_init() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'Countries', 'countries' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Country', 'countries' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search Countries', 'countries' ),
        'popular_items' => _x( 'Popular Countries', 'countries' ),
        'all_items' => _x( 'All Countries', 'countries' ),
        'parent_item' => _x( 'Parent Country', 'countries' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Country:', 'countries' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Country', 'countries' ),
        'update_item' => _x( 'Update Country', 'countries' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Country', 'countries' ),
        'new_item_name' => _x( 'New Country', 'countries' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => _x( 'Separate countries with commas', 'countries' ),
        'add_or_remove_items' => _x( 'Add or remove countries', 'countries' ),
        'choose_from_most_used' => _x( 'Choose from the most used countries', 'countries' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Countries', 'countries' ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => false,
        'hierarchical' => true,

        'rewrite' => true,
        'query_var' => true
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'countries', array('post'), $args );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that it extended the capability of it. But why it is not showing in the **Widget** or **Menu** area?

Comment: It must be showing in the Menus area. try checking the "Screen Options" on the top-right corner of the admin screen.